# How do I convert CV_8UC3 Mat to CV_32FC3?

Tags: opencv

Is there a way to convert from CV_8UC3 Mat to CV_32FC3 Mat without directly accessing the raw buffer? I tried `Mat::convertTo(newImage, CV_32FC3, 1.0);` but the colors end up wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The convention is, that for the type CV_8UC3 the pixels values range from 0 to 255, and for type CV_32FC3 from 0.0 to 1.0.  Thus you need to use a scaling factor of 1/255.0 instead of 1.0:

```
Mat::convertTo(newImage, CV_32FC3, 1/255.0);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this from the python bindings?