# Efficiency of summing images using MATLAB and OpenCV

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I am totally surprised by all of your answers. **Thank you very much!**

The bug code is showed as following:
`percentage = (double)kk * 100.0 / (double)totalnum;`

After I modified it to:
`percentage = (double)kk * 100.0 / totalnum;`

The problem is SOLVED. And this simple division consumed about 90s out of 150s. Maybe division between *double* and *int* is faster than it between *doubles*.

Again, thanks for all of your answers!

---

I'm trying to getting the average image from a set of pictures which come from a video. There are only 2 steps for this job:

1. Sum up all the images into a matrix.
2. Divide the matrix by the number of images.

I used following code in OpenCV: (C++)

```
Mat avIM = Mat::zeros(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, CV_32FC3);

for (ii = startnum; ii <= endnum; ii += interval) {
    string fullname = argv[1];
    sprintf(filename, "\\%d.png", ii);
    fullname.append(filename);

    Mat tempIM = imread(fullname.c_str());
    if (tempIM.empty()) { cout << "Can't open image!\n"; return -1; }
    tempIM.convertTo(tempIM, CV_32FC3);     

    avIM += tempIM;     //Sum up every image
    ++kk;

}
avIM = avIM * (double)(1.0 / kk);   //get average'
```

And following code in MatLab: (2015a)

```
avIM = zeros(size(imread([im.dir,'\',num2str(startnum),'.png'])));

pointIdx = startnum:interval:endnum;
for j=pointIdx,
    IM = imread([im.dir,'\',num2str(j),'.png']);
    avIM = avIM + double(IM); %Sum up every image
end
avIM = uint8(round(avIM./size(pointIdx,2))); %get average
```

But when I run those two program on 2,100 images, OpenCV took **150.3s**(Release) and MatLab took **103.1s**. It really confused me that a C++ program runs slower than a MatLab script.

So what's slowing down my OpenCV program? If it's caused by my method of matrix accessing, what should I do to improve the efficiency?

Comment: 1. is it possible that you are running in debug mode instead of release mode in Visual Studio? change it to release mode and run the program with Ctrl+F5
2. is the conversion to float necessary? can you originally read at as float ?

Comment: 1. Yes, it's a Release mode. 2. In fact, I'm just turning someone's code into C++ and I saw there is a (double) before IM. So I think I need a float-type matrix for summing these images.

Comment: Another possible issue: where are your images are located? is it possible that they are located on an external disk?

Comment: They're from the same folder and it's a hard drive(5400rpm) in my laptop. I've run them seperately with no background program running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems good enough, and in my tests I found it's running 10 times faster than Matlab code.

However, I show a slightly optimized code, that performs a little faster than yours.

**Notes**

Please note that I don't have a folder with images named as you, so I used `cv::glob` in C++ version, and `dir` in Matlab version to get the names of the images in the folder.

In my folder I have 82 small images, so the running time is obviously smaller than yours, but the relative performance should be reliable.

**Execution time**

```
                    Sum only      Get filenames + Sum
Matlab:             0.173543 s    (0.185308 s)
OpenCV @Seven Wang: 0.0145206 s   (0.0155748 s)
OpenCV @Miki:       0.0128943 s   (0.013333 s)
```

**Considerations**

Be sure that you're computing the running time consistently in OpenCV and Matlab.

---

**Code**

Matlab code:

```
tic

folder = 'D:\\SO\\temp\\old_075_6\\';
filenames = dir([folder '*.bmp']);

% Get rows and cols from 1st image
img = imread([folder name]);



S = zeros(size(img));

for ii = 1 : length(filenames)
    name = filenames(ii).name;
    currentImage = imread([folder name]);    
    S = S + double(currentImage);
end

S = uint8(round(S / length(filenames)));

toc
```

C++ code:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double ticLoad = double(cv::getTickCount());

    std::string folder = "D:\\SO\\temp\\old_075_6\\*.bmp";
    std::vector<cv::String> filenames;
    cv::glob(folder, filenames);

    int rows, cols;
    {
        // Just load the first image to get rows and cols
        cv::Mat3b img = cv::imread(filenames[0]);
        rows = img.rows;
        cols = img.cols;
    }

    /*{
        double tic = double(cv::getTickCount());

        cv::Mat3d S(rows, cols, 0.0);

        for (const auto& name : filenames)
        {
            cv::Mat currentImage = cv::imread(name);
            currentImage.convertTo(currentImage, CV_64F);

            S += currentImage;

        }
        S = S * double(1.0 / filenames.size());

        cv::Mat3b avg;
        S.convertTo(avg, CV_8U);

        double toc = double(cv::getTickCount());

        double timeLoad = (toc - ticLoad) / cv::getTickFrequency();
        double time = (toc - tic) / cv::getTickFrequency();
        std::cout << "@Seven Wang: " << time << " s (" << timeLoad << " s)" << std::endl;
    }*/

    {
        double tic = double(cv::getTickCount());

        cv::Mat3d S(rows, cols, 0.0);
        cv::Mat3b currentImage;

        for (const auto& name : filenames)
        {
            currentImage = cv::imread(name);
            cv::add(S, currentImage, S, cv::noArray(), CV_64F);
        }
        S /= filenames.size();

        cv::Mat3b avg;
        S.convertTo(avg, CV_8U);

        double toc = double(cv::getTickCount());

        double timeLoad = (toc - ticLoad) / cv::getTickFrequency();
        double time = (toc - tic) / cv::getTickFrequency();
        std::cout << "@Miki: " << time << " s (" << timeLoad << " s)" << std::endl;
    }
    getchar();






    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OMG, thanks for your analysis! But unfortunately it's totally my fault, which I didn't post on my question: `percentage = (double)kk * 100.0 / (double)totalnum;` This is the bug code which consumed my time. After changing it to `percentage = (double)kk * 100.0 / totalnum;`, the problem is totally SOLVED. Anyway, I'll study your code. Again, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

One point that drew my attention is the type "CV_32FC3". Are you specifically preferring that 32 bit float matrix and are you sure Matlab as well gets the pixel values the same way?

Because you have that extra step

```
tempIM.convertTo(tempIM, CV_32FC3);
```

in your Cpp code, where Matlab directly operates as soon as it retrieves the image without any conversion, which might be slowing down your cpp code. Furthermore, if Matlab is not getting the image in float values, that might be contributing the speed difference as float point arithmetics is a harder task for CPU to handle compared to integers.

Comment: That's a point. But in MatLab code, there is also an extra step: `avIM = avIM + double(IM);`

Comment: What step do you refer to?

Comment: Sorry I'm a new user here, I get confused with mini-Markdown formatting. What I mean is the **double()** on line 5, which also does type conversion.

Comment: I haven't search throughly, but here it says CV_32FC3 is between 0 and 1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724715/how-do-i-convert-cv-8uc3-mat-to-cv-32fc3. If Matlab is getting the matrix in integers (from 0 to 255), converting it to double would just do 0.0, 255.0, no complex operations. But in cpp, it would have to divide every number with floatpoint operations to get a result between 0 and 1. (again, if the referred page is correct)

Comment: @OE1 that might be a point. @Seven, can you compare again with [`im2double`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/im2double.html) instead of `double` in the MATLAB code? That would scale to `[0,1]` too, and make the comparison "fair".

Comment: @hbaderts Thanks for your advice. I'll modify my code and update after I get any result.

Comment: @hbaderts Alright, I made a foolish mistake and a simple double-type division consumed almost 90s out of 150s. Now the time is **64.20s** for CV_32SC3, **78.76s** for CV_32SC3 and **78.19s** for CV_64SC3.